# JAVA: Can someone explain this recursive code to me?

Tags: recursion

I have some practice questions for Java here. We are supposed to determine the answer without using a compiler.

Refer to the following method:

```
public static int  product(int n){
if (n <= 1)
    return 1;
else 
    return n * product(n-2);
}
```

What is the output when product(6) is called?

A) 1

B) 8

C) 12

D) 48

E) 70

According to the answers, the correct output is 48. I don't really understand why this is true. 
6 doesn't meet the base case, so it goes to the else statement. 
So 6, then product(6-2) = product(4), which goes to product(2), which goes to product(0)
so that produces 6 * 4, 4 * 2, 2 * 0, 0 * 0.  But that's 32, not 48? Is there something I'm missing?

product(25) returns -1181211311 for some reason, and I'm not really sure why this happens either. Is it because there's a stack overflow in the recursive calls or something?

Explanations would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: `product(6) = 6 * product(4) = 6 * (4 * product(2)) = 6 * (4 * (2 * product(0)))` and `product(0)` is 1, then: 6 * 4 * 2 * 1 is actually 48.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just answered the same thing in javascript here: [Need help understanding recursive function example from Eloquent Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049630/need-help-understanding-recursive-function-example-from-eloquent-javascript/23049810#23049810)

Basically it's a stack, but it's easier to think of it as a math equation:

n = 6 * product(4)

n = 6 * 4 * product(2)

n= 6 * 4 * 2 * product(0)

n = 6 * 4 * 2 * 1

n = 48

25 throws a huge negative number because it's bigger than the max value of int..

Answer (score 3):

The code works like this:

```
Round 1 : n = 6 so expression to be evaluated is 6 * product(4).
Round 2 : n = 4 so expression to be evaluated is 6 * 4 * product(2).
Round 3 : n = 2 so expression to be evaluated is 6 * 4 * 2 * product(0).
```

Since 0 < 1, the base case is reached, so `product(0) = 1`. Hence, the final expression is `6*4*2*1` which equals 48.

If you do this for 25, the value will overflow capacity of `int`, so you should change to `long`.

Comment: long won't fit the answer either

Comment: As per Oracle documentation, max value for `long` is 2^63 - 1 which evaluates to 9223372036854775807. Why shouldn't it fit then? I haven't tested it so I could be wrong of course :)

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I expressed myself poorly. I meant that using long won't solve the problem, because if you have product(50), for instance, it wouldn't fit a long :)

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros Actually 50 works too, but I appreciate the point you are trying to make.

Comment: for me, 50 returns 520469842636666622693081088000000. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros My bad. 50 will overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your code just multiplies the numbers from n to 1, decrementing by 2.

`product(25)` is supposed to return 7905853580625. Since it doesn't fit an int, your method will cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `product(0)` returns `1` because it meets the condition of `<= 1`, so the chain looks like this:

`6 * product(4), 4 * product(2), 2 * product(0), 1` => `6 * 8, 4 * 2, 2 * 1`

so, `6 * 8 = 48`

Second,

`product(25)` is an integer overflow. The maximum value you can store in an `int` is 2,147,483,647 (explanation here: [max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)), and your `product()` function, as written, would produce 7,905,853,580,625, much larger than that max value.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see answer is right. You are missing the main point that 2 will never be multiplied by 0. After product(2), 1 will be returned. When a method calls itself, new local variables and parameters are stored on the stack and method code will execute with these new variables from the start.

> when product(6) is called
>
> 1.return 6*product(6-2)
>
> product(4)
>
> 2.return 4*product(4-2)
>
> product(2)
>
> 3.return 2*product(2-2)
>
> product(0)
>
> 4.Which satisfies the if condition so 1 is returned
>
> Hence, 6*4*2=48